# Select query for Converting Oracle Rows to Columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table

```
ID-----Name------Value
1      City      New York
1      Country   USA
2      City      Barcelona
2      Country   Spain
```

Desired query output is

```
ID------City-------Country
1       New York   USA
2       Barcelona  Spain
```

Could you please let me know if this can be achieved using a query in Oracle. I came across two concepts listagg and pivote but not able to understand how to use those to achieve what I need.

I am getting the result in one way using listagg with the below query but all columns are coming in single column which I need to separate out.

```
select ID, 
       listagg(Name||';'||Value, ',') within group (order by Name) as Criteria
from table_name
group by ID;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it using aggregation:

```
select id, max(case when name = 'City' then value end) as city,
       max(case when name = 'Country' then value end) as country
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response Gordon Linoff, this fulfills the purpose I am looking for. Also can you please explain the reason of having max for my better understanding.

Comment: @Vinay . . . It is needed for the `group by`.  There should only be one value, so the `max()` just chooses it.

Answer (score 3):

Use `PIVOT`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bb691/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE countries ( ID, Name, Value ) AS
  SELECT 1, 'City',    'New York' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, 'Country', 'USA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'City',    'Barcelona' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Country', 'Spain' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   countries
PIVOT  ( MAX( value ) FOR name IN ( 'City' AS City, 'Country' AS Country ) )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bb691/1/0)**:

```
| ID |      CITY | COUNTRY |
|----|-----------|---------|
|  1 |  New York |     USA |
|  2 | Barcelona |   Spain |
```